# How to get wildcard suggestions in hibernate when onkeypress method is called?

Tags: javascript, hibernate

Html code

```
              <input type="text" name="keyword" id="key" onkeypress="searchKeyword ()">
```

The query part was included as it was given in another question like this.
JS code

```
              function searchKeyword (){
                 var s=document.getElementById ('key').value;
                 <%Session s=newHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory ().openSession ();
                 Criteria c= s.createCriteria (Keyword.class);
                  s.createQuery ("from Keyword where like:keyword").setParameter ("keyword",s+"%").list ();
       }%>
```

I need to get the letters which are currently typing and find the similar words from database. the var s cannot be included inside the query like this. How do I fix this so that the keys typed are passed to the query and compared with others in database

Answer (score 0):

What you've written won't work.

Your `searchKeyword()` javascript method should be making an AJAX call to a remote endpoint on your web application server.  This remote endpoint is basically an action or controller class that will intepret the incoming web request and call into either some business service or at a minimum some database repository implementation to perform the query.

In other words, you really should apply some type of MVC / Layered architecture here.

Web Page/View <-> Controller <-> Service <-> Repository/DAO

There are numerous articles online you can google to find out how to implement this type of architecture with minimal effort.